# Getting value of SQL date as String

Tags: java, sql-server

I am running a select query which selcts a SQL date type field.

The field appears in the table for example as "2010-10-10".

I want to get the field as a String, that is simply get a string with value: "2010-10-10" 
from my query.

How do i get it from the ResultSet rs?

Comment: Make a humble request: _Hey ResultSet, would you please mind giving me the date as a string?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What all you have to do is:

```
rs.getString(column);
```

Java Doc:

**Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.**